# Tensorflow embedding_lookup on multiple dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding

I would like to select a part of this tensor.

```
A = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], [[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]]])
```

The output of A will be

```
[[[1 1]
  [2 2]
  [3 3]]

 [[4 4]
  [5 5]
  [6 6]]]
```

The index I want to select from A is [1, 0]. I mean [2 2] of the first part and [4 4] of the second part of this tensor, so my expected result is

```
[2 2]
[4 4]
```

How can I do it with embedding_lookup function?

```
B = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(A, [1, 0])
```

I have already tried this

but it's not my expectation.

```
[[[4 4]
  [5 5]
  [6 6]]

 [[1 1]
  [2 2]
  [3 3]]]
```

Can anyone help me and explain how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to use exactly the `embedding_lookup` function? Are you okay to use other functions?

Comment: @thushv89 it's not necessary to be embedding_lookup function. I know only this function. If there's any other functions that can do what I expected, I would like to know that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
A = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], [[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]]])
B = [1,0]
inds = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(np.arange(len(B)), B)]

C = tf.gather_nd(params=A, indices=inds)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However my original model is more complex and if my B is tensor, not array. How can I do it without convert tensor to array? @thushv89

Comment: @PlafishyPhannakan Can you provide an example of what you mean?